# Выполнение 2х функций в одном файле javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Изобретаю велосипед, и столкнулась с проблемой.
Есть код, в котором должны обрабатываться 2 клика. Проблема в том, что вторая часть не срабатывает в файле, но срабатывает в консоли.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var a = $(".aside-list");
  $(a).click(function() {
    $(a).not(this).addClass("hidden");
    $(this).addClass("vis");
  });
  $(".vis").click(function hide() {
    $(a).removeClass("hidden") ;
    $(a).removeClass("vis") ;
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда пишешь так `$(".vis").click(` - то обработчик навешивается "вникуда", т.к. такого элемента на странице нет. Попробуй так:

```
$(document).on('click', '.vis', function(){
// ...
});
```

Вместо `document` лучше поставить селектор элемента, который является родителем по отношению к `.vis`

например если html такой

```
<div id="test">
    <a href="#" class="aside-list">Hello</a>
</div>
```

то лучше писать

```
$('#test').on('click', '.vis', function(){
// ...
});
```

---

Не знаю, эта ли логика затевалась

```js
  var a = '.aside-list';
  $('#test').on('click', a, function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();
    $(a).not(this).addClass("hidden");
    $(this).addClass("vis");
  });
  
  $('#test').on('click', '.vis', function(e){        
    e.preventDefault();
    $(a).removeClass("hidden");
    $(a).removeClass("vis") ;
  });
```

```css
.hidden {
  color: red;
}

.vis {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
    <a href="#" class="aside-list">11</a>
    <a href="#" class="aside-list">22</a>
    <a href="#" class="aside-list">33</a>  
</div>
```

Comment: Затевалось раскрытие/скрытие элемента по клику родителя.     
            '<ul>
                <li class="aside-list">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
                <li class="aside-list">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
                <li class="aside-list">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
                <li class="aside-list">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
                <li class="aside-list">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
              </ul>'         Вариант с .on() вообще всё сломал

Comment: А нет, работает! Спасибо большое!